# Which package should I use in CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: moveit, catkin, cmake, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use the MoveIt! package on ROS indigo, and I am following the tutorial at http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/pr2_moveit_tutorials/html/planning/src/doc/move_group_interface_tutorial.html.

As an example of how to use MoveIt! in C++, the tutorial provides the following line:

```
moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup group("right_arm");
```

What I am trying to figure out, is how to actually compile this. So, I have built a new ROS package, and in the `CMakeLists.txt` file for that package, I need to specify where to look for header and library files. But **how do I know the name of the package that is required for the above code?**

If I look in `/opt/ros/indigo/include`, there are various directories such as  `moveit`, `moveit_msgs`, `moveit_planners_ompl`, and similarly in `/opt/ros/indigo/lib` and `/opt/ros/indigo/share`. Is each of these directories a package, or is each one a node, or something else?

After doing a bit of research, I found that the `moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup` class from the above code is defined in `/opt/ros/indigo/include/moveit/move_group_interface/move_group.h`. This suggests to me that I should be using the `moveit` or `move_group_interface` packages, but if I try either of these, then it fails. For example, in my `CMakeLists.txt` file, if I have:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp rospy std_msgs genmsg moveit)
```

And then I try to build my package, it tells me:

```
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "moveit"
```

And similarly for `move_group_interface`.

So I'm obviously a bit confused as to what ROS packages actually are, where they are stored on my machine, and how to know which one I should be referencing in `CMakeLists.txt`. Any help? Thanks :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209890/which-package-should-i-use-in-cmakelists.txt?/) by [Karnivaurus](https://answers.ros.org/users/21659/karnivaurus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2015-05-25

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-05-26**:
Isn't this a sort-of duplicate of [Writing a simple CMakeLists.txt file for ROS](http://answers.ros.org/question/209887/writing-a-simple-cmakeliststxt-file-for-ros/)?

**Comment by [Fleurmond](https://answers.ros.org/users/22507/fleurmond/) on 2015-05-26**:
That could be true. But I think the title of both questions are really evasive. Then, it could be hard to find is someone already asked this question. And theirs problems look different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had same problem here : http://answers.ros.org/question/249354/how-to-install-move_group_interface-from-source/
The solution for move_group_interface is

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
   moveit_ros_planning_interface
   ..... 
)
```

---

Originally posted by [robbycandra](https://answers.ros.org/users/28202/robbycandra/) with karma: 71 on 2016-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In case it helps anyone else, I made a list of all the package names:

- moveit_commander moveit_core
- moveit_fake_controller_manager
- moveit_msgs
- moveit_planners_ompl
- moveit_ros_benchmarks
- moveit_ros_benchmarks_gui
- moveit_ros_control_interface
- moveit_ros_manipulation
- moveit_ros_move_group
- moveit_ros_perception
- moveit_ros_planning
- moveit_ros_planning_interface
- moveit_ros_robot_interaction
- moveit_ros_visualization
- moveit_ros_warehouse
- moveit_setup_assistant
- moveit_simple_controller_manager
- rqt_moveit

And includes are of the form:

```
#include <moveit/[namespace]/[header].h>
```

E.g.:

```
#include <moveit/robot_model_loader/robot_model_loader.h>
```

---

Originally posted by [boone](https://answers.ros.org/users/28826/boone/) with karma: 21 on 2016-12-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-18**:
Note that this isn't really moveit specific: this is the regular include pattern for all ROS C++ packages.